# Generate a Window from Core Data

Tags: cocoa, core-data, interface-builder

To start, I put my info into Core Data and I have my table showing up in Interface Builder. It has 20 atributes that are the same except for the number after them ie. example1, example2, etc. Each of these atributes has 12 items for the user to change with 3 variables each(on,off or random).

I want these choices for the user to change to come up in a new window. I don't want to bind each of these variables by hand! Is there a way to bind the whole window?

And should I use an interface builder plugin and make a master window or make 20 windows or ??? I'm a complete novice, but would like to do this the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to change UI labels/column-titles. If so, you can bind the text of the label to either data or an attribute of the controller that configures the label for the current state of the data.

If you have repeating units of data, you can define a cell which is bound to a controller and then use as many instances of the cell as needed. See NSMatrix and related containers.

Comment: Thanks. I'll mark this as answered because I don't think I have the knowledge yet to get this working. I got excited because Core Data let me put all my table into interface builder right away, but I really have to go back and get some more fundamentals. I'm used to working backwards to learn and breaking things apart to learn, but I'm having a hard time doing that with Objective C. Through searching I found a lot of references to SimpleMultiWindow example code that Apple provided, but it's gone now. Is there another example project that good to look at?